# Migrate CoreData enum to SwiftData

Tags: core-data, swift-data

I have a simple CoreData object that includes an enum, and when I try to migrate to SwiftData the data is removed and the app crashes. How can this be avoided? I feel like the automatic migration should properly handle this, but maybe I'm missing a step.

To reproduce, follow the steps below.

1. Run the CoreData version of the application
2. Add a few items
3. Check the sqlite file
4. Run the SwiftData version of the application

Observe the application is now in a bad state. If you pull up the sqlite file, you'll see that the `difficulty` column is now null.

[image]

```
@objc
public class Item : NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var difficulty: Difficulty
    @NSManaged public var timestamp: Date
}

@objc
public enum Difficulty: Int64, Codable, CaseIterable, Identifiable{
    case easy
    case medium
    case hard
    case expert
    
    var title: String{
        switch self {
        case .easy:
            return "Easy"
        case .medium:
            return "Medium"
        case .hard:
            return "Hard"
        case .expert:
            return "Expert"
        }
    }
    
    public var id: String{
        title
    }
}
```

```
@Model
public class Item{
    public var difficulty: Difficulty
    public var timestamp: Date
    
    init(difficulty: Difficulty, timestamp: Date) {
        self.difficulty = difficulty
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}

public enum Difficulty: Int, Codable, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case easy
    case medium
    case hard
    case expert
    
    var title: String{
        switch self {
        case .easy:
            return "Easy"
        case .medium:
            return "Medium"
        case .hard:
            return "Hard"
        case .expert:
            return "Expert"
        }
    }
    
    public var id: String{
        title
    }
}
```

Comment: If you let Xcode migrate the model it will use Int64 as the type for the difficulty property so maybe you should start there and then in  a second step migrate to the enum or use a computed property

Comment: @JoakimDanielson this is exactly what I found out late last night. If I use a regular integer instead of the difficulty, Enum, the migration works successfully. Presumably, doing a manual migration after that to use the Enum should work. Not ideal.

Comment: I filed a feedback to Apple and this is the following response I got: This is due to Core Data representing the enum as a integer64 but in SwiftData the difficulty enum is represented by a Composite Attribute, this migration is not lossless as the attribute types are different.

Please update the difficulty in the Core Data stack to a Composite Attribute that aligns with the one created in SwiftData.